# Infamous 'byte sequence" error with local install of gitorious on Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-1.9, gitorious

I am trying to install gitorious on my personal server but I am not very familiar with Ruby or the frameworks and scripts involved in getting to the finish line.

I am following the following instructions to install gitorious on my CentOS 5.4 server:

```
http://www.tikalk.com/alm/blog/installing-gitorious-centos-55
```

The site comes up but as soon as I click on the login link I get the 500 error screen and an exception report is emailed to me.  The error is reported as an "invalid byte sequence" and google tells me that it's related to Ruby 1.9.  From what I've read, gitorious.org is using 1.9 and others got it working, so now I'm curious as to why it's not working on my system.

Judging from the backtrace, it looks like the invalid encoding might be coming from the database which is a MySQL 5.0.77 in my case.  All tables in the gitorious database have their DEFAULT_CHARSET set to utf8.

You can make out the version of most components that I have installed from the stack.  I have rails 3.0.0 installed.  If anything else would be useful, please comment and I'll reply.

The exception report goes like this:

```
A ArgumentError occurred in sessions#new:

 invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template_error.rb:43:in `split'

-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

 * URL       : http://[my-server]/login
 * IP address: [my-ip]
 * Parameters: {"controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"new"}
 * Rails root: /opt/gitorious/gitorious

-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

 * session id: nil
 * data: nil

-------------------------------
Environment:
-------------------------------

 * DOCUMENT_ROOT                               : /var/www/gitorious/public
 * HTTP_ACCEPT                                 : application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
 * HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING                        : gzip, deflate
 * HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE                        : en-us
 * HTTP_CONNECTION                             : keep-alive
 * HTTP_COOKIE                                 : _gitorious_sess=1a4c10ada66c96f213d6f4573d35286c
 * HTTP_HOST                                   : [my-hostname]
 * HTTP_REFERER                                : http://[my-hostname]/
 * HTTP_USER_AGENT                             : Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7
 * PATH_INFO                                   : /login
 * QUERY_STRING                                :
 * REMOTE_ADDR                                 : [my-ip]
 * REMOTE_PORT                                 : 53586
 * REQUEST_METHOD                              : GET
 * REQUEST_URI                                 : /login
 * SCRIPT_NAME                                 :
 * SCRIPT_URI                                  : http://[my-server]/login
 * SCRIPT_URL                                  : /login
 * SERVER_ADDR                                 : [client-ip]
 * SERVER_ADMIN                                : root@localhost
 * SERVER_NAME                                 : [my-hostname]
 * SERVER_PORT                                 : 80
 * SERVER_PROTOCOL                             : HTTP/1.1
 * SERVER_SOFTWARE                             : Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
 * _                                           : _
 * action_controller.request.path_parameters   : {"controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"new"}
 * action_controller.request.query_parameters  : {}
 * action_controller.request.request_parameters: {}
 * action_controller.rescue.request            : #
 * action_controller.rescue.response           : #
 * rack.errors                                 : #
 * rack.input                                  : #
 * rack.multiprocess                           : true
 * rack.multithread                            : false
 * rack.request.cookie_hash                    : {"_gitorious_sess"=>"1a4c10ada66c96f213d6f4573d35286c"}
 * rack.request.cookie_string                  : _gitorious_sess=1a4c10ada66c96f213d6f4573d35286c
 * rack.request.query_hash                     : {}
 * rack.request.query_string                   :
 * rack.run_once                               : false
 * rack.session                                : {}
 * rack.session.options                        : {:key=>"_gitorious_sess", :path=>"/", :domain=>".", :expire_after=>21 days, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :cookie_only=>true, :secret=>"dopFactAnArcyirUckryfsObNohokOrOmFeinwojUpbofIamcicyesicCulfaydd", :id=>"1a4c10ada66c96f213d6f4573d35286c"}
 * rack.session.record                         : #
 * rack.url_scheme                             : http
 * rack.version                                : [1, 0]

 * Process: 22046
 * Server : [my-server]

-------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template_error.rb:43:in `split'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template_error.rb:43:in `source_extract'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template_error.rb:86:in `compute_backtrace'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template_error.rb:11:in `initialize'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb:212:in `new'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb:212:in `rescue in render_template'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1250:in `render_for_file'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:945:in `render'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `block in render_with_benchmark'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `block in ms'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1326:in `default_render'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1332:in `perform_action'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `block in perform_action_with_benchmark'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `block in ms'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action_with_flash'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `block in build_middleware_stack'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/rack/metal.rb:47:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:122:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `block in call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
 :8:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
 [RAILS_ROOT]/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:441:in `start_request_handler'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:381:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:252:in `safe_fork'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:377:in `handle_spawn_application'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:222:in `start'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rails_application'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:247:in `block in spawn_rails_application'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `block in synchronize'
 :8:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rails_application'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:145:in `spawn_application'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:278:in `handle_spawn_application'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
 /usr/local/ruby/ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.15/bin/passenger-spawn-server:61:in `'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/gitorious/browse_thread/thread/c72bd1c916e429e8#cf97f6d22d13ec31) by Marius Mårnes Mathiesen, he recommends removing the i18n gem. Maybe that solves your problem.

Comment: I am unable to test this solution as I posted this a while ago, but it looks valid and I appreciate the response.  I will give this a shot if I get back to setting up my server again.